# I try to iterate vector which in iterate vector

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I don't know why I get Segmentation Fault here. I try to make prime finding function.

I create the vector call "numbers" which contain the numbers from const min to const max and If it's a prime. It will turn the multiply of that number to 1 and add the prime number to vector name "p_numbers", min will only be prime numbers, but it doesn't matter because I got Segmentation Fault. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>




std::vector<int> primes_between(const int unsigned min, const unsigned int max)
{
    std::vector <int> numbers;
    for (int i=min; i<= max; i++) numbers.push_back(i);
    std::vector<int> p_numbers;
    auto start = numbers.begin();
    auto end = numbers.end();
    
    for (int value : numbers)
    {
        if (value != 1)
        {
            p_numbers.push_back(value);
            for (auto itr = start+value-min; itr != end; itr += value) *itr = 1;
        }
    }
    
    return p_numbers;
    
}
```

Comment: `itr != end;` are you sure that this becomes `false` at some point? Iterator based loops are less error prone often but not always.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/cP6eTYEjz - probably you are jumping with `it` beyond `end()`.

Comment: As you surely know, incrementing the `end()` iterator is undefined behavior. What do you think happens in `for (auto itr = start+value-min; itr != end; itr += value)` when you do `itr += value`? You're most likely going to blast past the `end()` by a large margin. Probably test `*itr + value <= max` (not tested) instead of `itr != end` so that it stops short of incrementing 1 too many times.

Comment: If you use your debugger to step through this function, one line at a time, and calling with two parameters: one million, and one million plus 1, the reason for the segmentation fault will be obvious. Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: Your algorithm is strange. It doesn't seems to do what function name suggests. I have no clue what is your idea of solution. What this part `auto itr = start+value-min` do?

Comment: You seem to be confused about `value`. Some of your code assumes it a small integer (e.g. `value != 1`, `itr += value`) when really it's a value between `min` and `max` which could be a very large number indeed. It takes a bit of practise to see the code you have written for what it really is, instead of what you think it is. As mentioned already a debugger can help with this.

Comment: If iterators did work as you seem to assume, and you passed this 4 and 10, it would claim that 4, 6, and 9 are primes. (You can't do "the sieve" on an interval like this.)

Comment: This looks like an attempt of a very twisted version of the Eratosthenes sieve. Hint: keep it simple.

Comment: The _extreme value theorem_ of debugging suggests that you consider extreme inputs.  For example, when `min` and `max` are both `1000`.  This will push a single `1000` into `numbers`  Then the first iteration of your loop begins with start at the first element (`start + 1000 - 1000` is `start + 0` ... or is it? possibly not, might needs some `()`'s), then increments `itr` by `1000` putting it **way** beyond the end of the vector.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It's not so much "twisted" as a misunderstanding of how and why the sieve works.

Comment: Fix "TODO" here: https://godbolt.org/z/T5dYE8e3e

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, your iterator is increased too much, going beyond the end of the vector, but your condition doesn't catch it.
You can fix it by changing the loop to check that `itr < end`, instead of `itr != end`:

```
for (auto itr = start + (value - min); itr < end; itr += value)
```

But then your function gives correct results only if min is 1 or 2. The problem is conceptual: you assume that the first time a number appears in your vector it must be a prime, and then you set all its multiples to 1, to ignore them. It's the [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). But if you start from 10, 10 will be considered a prime, because no number cancelled it. If you had started from 1 or 2, 10 would have been cancelled (that is, set to 1) on reaching 2 and 5. But since you start from 10, it's considered a prime.

To solve this problem you should change the function: it cannot accept a `min`, as min has to be set to 1 or 2. You can change it to

```
std::vector<int> primes_between(const unsigned int max)
{
    constexpr unsigned int min = 2;
    ...
```

Otherwise, if you really want to choose the minimum number, you have to start calculating from 2 (there's no way to avoid it if you use the sieve of Eratosthenes) and then, at the end, discard all the values less than `min`.

Comment: "You can fix it by changing the loop to check that itr < end..." No that doesn't fix it. Over-incrememting an iterator is already undefined behavior.

Comment: @RaymondChen Ouch, you are right. I'm a bit too busy at the moment, but I'll fix it when I have some time - hopefully tonight.